# Node.js - Generate hashed password using bcrypt

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to generate hashed password using bcrypt and log it in terminal. But the logged result is not as per my expected output

My controller function is as follows,

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const { hashedPassword } = require('../lib/passwordHash');

exports.create = (req, res) => {
  const { body } = req;

  console.log('1 Create');

  const { password } = body;
  console.log('2 ', password);

  const newPassword = hashedPassword(password);
  console.log('3 ', newPassword);

  res.send('Create');
};
```

passwordHash.js is as follows,

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const saltRounds = 10;

const hashedPassword = (password) =>
  bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) {
      return err;
    }
    console.log(hash);
    return hash;
  });

module.exports = {
  hashedPassword
};
```

Output is as follows,

```
1 Create
2  12345
3  undefined
$2b$10$hVQ7J4ratfP7ubgiRzF1WOI7rmYC5WRo4kFh6EbjJtK0qR1gW5nWa
```

Expected the Output to be,

```
1 Create
2  12345
$2b$10$hVQ7J4ratfP7ubgiRzF1WOI7rmYC5WRo4kFh6EbjJtK0qR1gW5nWa
3 $2b$10$hVQ7J4ratfP7ubgiRzF1WOI7rmYC5WRo4kFh6EbjJtK0qR1gW5nWa
```

I understand that it is an asynchronous function which runs after all the lines are executed. But how can i get the expected result.